# Custom (multi-column) <div> in AsciiDoctor?

Tags: asciidoctor

I'd like to layout (and maybe print) my AsciiDoctor document, which is a cheatsheet with mostly tables.

What is the best way to get a multi-column HTML output and also get multi-column PDF for printing?

I've found that

```
#col {-moz-column-count: 2;-webkit-column-count: 2;column-count: 2;}
```

can be used in the HTML with a `<div>`, but so far I modified the HTML manually. (I'm only guessing a bit what to do, since I'm not a web-developer.)

Is there a way to include this style and div in the AsciiDoctor source file?

What is the best way to get a multi-column PDF?

Comment: Hi Gerenuk, Did you ever solve this problem?

Comment: Someone showed me that there was some hard-coded width in the result (cannot remember which line that was). Removing that produced a two column HTML, which was kind of ok. But, of course, in HTML the content goes down the full first column, which isn't what I wanted. For now I decided that maybe a searchable HTML with a table of contents isn't that bad after all.

Answer (score 3):

This describes how to do this for HTML.

You can add CSS as passthrough-content (++++) when using HTML output. Your example would look like this:

```
++++
<style>
#col {-moz-column-count: 2;-webkit-column-count: 2;column-count: 2;}
</style>
++++
```

You could then add a div around some content using passthrough content as well:

```
++++
<div id="col">
++++

This

Is 

Multicolumn 

text

++++
</div>
++++
```

But to assign an ID to a block you could write in a more portable way

```
[[col]]
--
This

Is 

Multicolumn 

text
--
```

As `#col` is a CSS selector for an ID of an element, it might be more convenient to use a CSS class `.col` instead. You can then have multiple blocks with the same style like this - note that this is now using single brackets for the block style instead of the double brackets above for the ID.

```
++++
<style>
.col {-moz-column-count: 2;-webkit-column-count: 2;column-count: 2;}
</style>
++++

[col]
--
This

Is 

Multicolumn 

text
--

[col]
--
This

Is 

Multicolumn 

text
--
```

The last snippet would produce the following:

[image: Two Column layout]